# Issue with numpy.concatenation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have defined 2 numpy array 2,3 and horizontally concatenate them

```
a=numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b=numpy.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
C=numpy.concatenate((a,b),axis=0)
```

c becomes 4,3 matrix
Now I tried same thing with 1,3 list as

```
a=numpy.array([1,2,3])
b=numpy.array([4,5,6])
c=numpy.concatenate((a,b),axis=0)
```

Now I was expecting 2,3 matrix but instead I have 1,6. I understand that vstack etc will work but I am curious as to why this is happening? And what I am doing wrong with numpy.concatenate?

Thanks for the reply. I can get the result as suggested by having 1,3 array and then concatenation. But logic is I have to add rows to an empty matrix at each iteration. I tried append as Suggested:

```
testing=[]
for i in range(3):
   testing=testing.append([1,2,3])
```

It gave error testing doesnot have attribute append as its of None Type. Further If I use logic of 1,3 array using np.array([[1,2,3]]) how can i do this inside for loop?

Comment: Use `testing.append([1,2,3])` instead of `testing=testing.append([1,2,3])`

Comment: According to the `vstack` code, it first passes the arrays through `atleast_2d`, turning your `(3,)` arrays into `(1,3)` ones.  Ask yourself, what is `axis=0` in the 2 situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong. [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) join a sequence of arrays together.which means it create an integrated array from the current array's element which in a 2D array the elements are nested lists and in a 1D array the elements are variables.

So this is not the `concatenate`'s job, as you said you can use `np.vstack` :

```
>>> c=numpy.vstack((a,b))
>>> c
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Also in your code `list.append` appends and element in-place to a list you can not assign it to a variable.instead you can just `append` to `testing` in each iteration.

```
testing=[]
for i in range(3):
   testing.append([1,2,3])
```

also as a more efficient way you can create that list using a list comprehension list following :

```
testing=[[1,2,3] for _ in xrange(3)]
```

Comment: Thanks how can i then get 2,3 matrix using concatenate only?

Comment: @AashishsharmaSharma That's not the `concatenate` job!

Comment: In essence I cannot tell python in advance that wait it will be list of list. More rows to follow? As basically I am trying to create empty list say A=[]. Then in for loop in 1st iteration I want to add 1st row in 2nd iteration 2nd and So on. I was using A=np.concatenate((A,[1,2,3]))

Comment: @AashishsharmaSharma So what you don't use `list.append` method?

Comment: I tried list.append but it gave error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append. I checked a=[] is not list but none type object

Comment: @AashishsharmaSharma I can not give any idea till i see your code! you need to add a good explanation in your question! if you want to get a desire answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are concatenating along `axis=0`.

In your first example:

```
a=numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])     # 2 elements in 0th dimension 
b=numpy.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])  # 2 elements in 0th dimension
C=numpy.concatenate((a,b),axis=0)    # 4 elements in 0th dimension
```

In your second example:

```
a=numpy.array([1,2,3])               # 3 elements in 0th dimension
b=numpy.array([4,5,6])               # 3 elements in 0th dimension     
c=numpy.concatenate((a,b),axis=0)    # 6 elements in 0th dimension
```

Edit:

Note that in your second example, you only have one dimensional array.

```
In [35]: a=numpy.array([1,2,3])

In [36]: a.shape
Out[36]: (3,)
```

If the shape of the arrays was `(1,3)` you would get your expected result:

```
In [43]: a2=numpy.array([[1,2,3]])

In [44]: b2=numpy.array([[4,5,6]])

In [45]: numpy.concatenate((a2,b2), axis=0)
Out[45]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Sorry I  don't understand. In my first example it was 2,3 so 0th dimension has 2 elements and 1st dimension 3. In my second example I have 1,3 array so should'nt 0th dimension have 1 element?

Comment: @AashishsharmaSharma, no, in your second example, your array only has one dimension it is shape `(3,)`, if the shape was indeed `(1,3)` you would get your expected result.

Comment: @ Akavali Thanks that worked as you said but problem is I have to start from empty list/array. So its like a=[]. Then for loop and inside it at each iteration I add new row. with syntax a=np.concatenate((a,[1,2,3])). I can create 1,3 array as you mentioned by np.array([[1,2,3]]) but how to do that inside for loop?